# Inherit Maui.SplashTheme and customize it in MAUI app

Tags: android, maui, styling

I'm developing a MAUI app with .NET 8 targeting Android.

Everything works well with the default theme @style/Maui.SplashTheme in my **MainActivity.cs**.

But I need to edit the theme and add some configuration, because my **DatePicker's dialog** doesn't show well the dialog buttons (OK/Cancel):

[image]

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77259114/833644) answer I created my own **style.xml** and set my color values, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources> 
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">  
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>  
    </style> 

    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">  
         <!--header background-->  
         <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>  
         <!--header textcolor-->  
         <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#00ff00</item>  
         <!--body background-->  
         <item name="android:windowBackground">#0000ff</item>  
         <!--selected day-->  
         <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff1111</item>  
         <!--days of the month-->  
         <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>  
         <!--days of the week-->  
         <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#33ff33</item>  
         <!--cancel&ok-->  
         <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>  
    </style> 
</resources>
```

Now, in my MainActivity, If I replace...

```
Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme"
```

With:

```
Theme = "@style/MyTheme"
```

...I can solve my problem and change every color of the dialog.

But now I have other issues in my app: I don't have the splash screen (and I want it) and also the Shell Flyout doesn't work as expected.
I've also read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#platform-specific-configuration) that I should keep the default theme in my MainActivity.cs.

So, my question is: is it possibile to override in any way the @style/Maui.SplashTheme theme with a custom theme (possibly in my style.xml file)?
In this way I could keep everything of my SplashTheme.

I was expecting something like this (look at **parent="Maui.SplashTheme"**), but it is not working (I don't receive errors or warnings, but the theme simply doesn't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <!--header background-->
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
        <!--header textcolor-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#00ff00</item>
        <!--body background-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#0000ff</item>
        <!--selected day-->
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff1111</item>
        <!--days of the month-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <!--days of the week-->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#33ff33</item>
        <!--cancel&ok-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Your Maui project should contain a styles.xml under "Platforms\Android\Resources\values\styles.xml". You can add your modifications there, there is no need to change your activity to point to another style. Which version of .NET MAUI are you using? The main theme nowadays is: "Maui.MainTheme"

Comment: @Cybrosys thank for helping! I didn't have that file in the initial project (I think it's normal, reading the other answer). I created it, edited and it works, but only if I use Theme = "@style/MyTheme" in my activity. But if I do it, I loose the SplashTheme theme...

Comment: @Cybrosys I just created the project a few weeks ago with .NET 8

Comment: Ok. Try changing your style tag to: <style name="Maui.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"></style> and add your <item android:datePicker...> there. Your main activity should still use: "@style/Maui.SplashTheme"

Comment: @Cybrosys it works!! Thank a lot! Please write the answer and I will set it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base theme for new .NET MAUI applications on Android is "Maui.MainTheme". Update your styles.xml to look like this (I don't know if you still want/need the windowIsTranslucent entry):

```
    <style name="Maui.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <!--header background-->
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
        <!--header textcolor-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#00ff00</item>
        <!--body background-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#0000ff</item>
        <!--selected day-->
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff1111</item>
        <!--days of the month-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <!--days of the week-->
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#33ff33</item>
        <!--cancel&ok-->
        <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>
    </style>
```

Your activity should use the default splash theme:

```
Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme"
```